# Add second disk to encrypted laptop

Tags: encryption, luks

I have installed cleanly 14.04 AMD64 onto my laptop which has two (SSD) disks. I used the default install with full disk encryption option on the first disk. However I'd now like to add a second disk to the machine, and I'd like that also to be encrypted in the same way.

I'd like the second disk to either be added to the space the first disk as, so it's all just seen as one volume. If that's not possible then having the second disk as /home (and also fully encrypted) is fine too.

Note: I'm not using ecryptfs.

How can I easily add the second disk to the full disk encryption setup?

Comment: Followed this guide and it worked a treat. http://lowtek.ca/roo/2012/how-to-add-second-drive-to-luks-ubuntu/